# не могу вызвать метод геттера с Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

хотел протестить работу с Lombok, вписал аннотацию @Data, если пытаться вызвать метод у переменной класса, то код красный высвечивается, на видео я делаю как он делает, но у меня не получается так делать как у него. Прикладываю код класса с @Data. Также пробовал с @Getter и @Setter, тоже не помогло, пытался обновить мавен, тоже не помогло.

```
package project.telegrambot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource ("application.properties")
public class BotConfig {
    @Value ("${bot.name}")
    String botName;
    @Value ("${bot.token}")
    String botToken;
}
```

Прикладываю скриншот чтобы понятнее было какая у меня проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также pom.xml прикладываю:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>project</groupId>
  <artifactId>telegrambot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>telegrambot</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>6.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.28</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: забыл сказать, что я использую JDK 17, пишут что ломбок уже не актуален с 17 версии, так ли это?

Comment: У вас используется не семнадцатая JDK, а седьмая!  `<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>`

Comment: @NowhereMan уже не важно, протестил на разных версиях, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Всё, пофиксил переустановкой IDE, больше не нужна помощь